# Is there a place where I could get Dummy tasks on Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am a beginner on Lightning Experience,and have done quite a few trailheads on Lightning experience..I want to nourish my skills acquired during trailheads.Is there a place where I could get Dummy tasks on Lightning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a feature that's currently not available in lightning experience and build a component for app builder or community builder. You can put some time building them and putting on appexchange and that way you will learn more.

Some of things that lightning experience is missing is

Opportunity split

Charting components to show SFDC report.

Take a third party JS library built in jquery and try to get it working inside a component. There is lot to build and explore in components currently.